# Find specific word and add class with JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, contains

I want to add a class to a specific word.

In the example below I am trying to change the text 'EN' and replace it with an image.

**HTML**

```
<li class="language-btn"><a title="English" href="https://website.com/"><span>EN</span></a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.en-flag { background-image: url("https://website.com/english-flag.png");}
```

**JQuery**

```
(function($) {
$('li.language-btn a span:contains("EN")').closest('li.language-btn').find("span").addClass("en-flag");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've created a function but you haven't **run** it. You need to add `(jQuery)` at the end before the `;` (to use the usual pattern of a wrapper function taking `jQuery` and receiving it as `$`).

Comment: That said, you should remove the entire `.closest('li.language-btn').find("span")` part of that. You already selected the `span` you want with the selector. So just: `$('li.language-btn a span:contains("EN")').addClass("en-flag");`

Comment: In case my first comment above wasn't clear, here it is in practice: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ypa5qmc9/ Basically, change the last line from `});` to `})(jQuery);`

Comment: Thanks that works! Also how can I remove 'EN' or force the image to be on top of the text?

Comment: You can empty the span with [`empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/). But you might need to add to your class to ensure the element has width.